# Error en Realm : UnsupportedOperationException: Missing right-hand side of OR

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en realm. Tengo un array con los id que quiero y me da este error:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Missing right-hand side of OR
```

cuando hago la iguacion de RealmQuery a RealmResult, hago este igualacion ya que necesito RealmResult para el constructor del adapter.

Os dejo el codigo:

```
private RealmQuery<Clothes> query;
private RealmResults<Clothes> clothes = null;



    query = realm.where(Clothes.class);

    if(listClothesIDString != null) {
        String[] partsID = listClothesIDString.split("-");
        Integer[] partsIDInt = new Integer[partsID.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < partsID.length; i++) {
            partsIDInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(partsID[i]);
        }

        for (Integer id : partsIDInt) {
            query = query.or().equalTo("id", id);
        }

        clothes = query.findAll(); // Aqui da el error¡¡¡
    }
```

Comment: Has revisando cuantos elementos tienes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes solo un elemento en `partsIDInt` se provocará el error que comentas:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Missing right-hand side of OR

Realiza esta validación:

```
...
...
int  i = 0;
for (int id : partsIDInt) {
    if (i++ > 0) {  //* mayor a un elemento se usa OR!
        query = query.or();
    }
    query = query.equalTo("id", id);
}
...
...
```